# WebSQL:table not creating on changing window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-sql

I'm trying to store data when the user clicks on submit button.

Here is the code:

```
var db = openDatabase('CBDB', '1.0', 'mySpecialDatabaseThatWontWork',10*1024*1024);
db.transaction(function (nw) {
    nw.executeSql('Drop TABLE user');
});

function db1(){
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(empid varchar(10))');
        var x = $('#nameT').val();
        console.log(x);
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO user (empid) VALUES (?)', [x]);
    });
    window.location.assign("www/landing.html");
}
```

Now, if I comment the window.location then the code works fine. But when the window is redirected to a new page the table is not created.

Any problem with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO user (empid) VALUES (?)', [x], function red(){window.location.assign("www/landing.html");});
```